# What are the uses of morphs column type in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

What kind of data can be stored with $table->morphs column type?

```
$table->morphs('taggable');
```

I do not fully understand the explationation given [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns).

> Adds taggable_id UNSIGNED BIGINT and taggable_type VARCHAR equivalent
>   columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $table->morphs('taggable'); Adds taggable_id UNSIGNED BIGINT and taggable_type VARCHAR equivalent columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$table->morphs('column_name')` is a shortcut, it will create 2 columns:

`column_name_id` with **unsigned integer** datatype and

`column_name_type` with **string** datatype to create *polymorphic relationship*

so

```
$table->morphs('taggable');
```

is the same as:

```
$table->unsignedInteger("taggable_id");
$table->string("taggable_type");
```

Comment: I see. So it is for holding Polymorphic relationships. Right?

Answer (score 4):

> **Laravel Morphs are used to create relationship of two tables with a
> common child(property) table.**

For example there are two tables

1. Pages
2. Posts

*Now Pages and Posts both have a common property comment, so there will be a common table `comments`*

[image: Pages and Posts has a morph relation with comments table]

```
$table->morphs('commentable');
```

For More details visit https://blog.logrocket.com/polymorphic-relationships-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Morphs are used to create relationship of two tables with a common child(property) table.
So To relation two table in database, we can use this morphs column.
Like

> ```
>     $table->uuid('id')->primary();
>     $table->string('type');
>     $table->morphs('notifiable');
>     $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
>     $table->timestamps();
> ```